# How do I control the "more" link from a views content pane to point to a biblio filtered page

Tags: 6, views

I'm using Drupal 6. I'm trying to create a view pane that lists three biblio items matching a particular term, and then offers a link to more items filtered using the same term. Biblio allows me to access these items nicely using `biblio/term/term_name`. Is there a way to control the `more` link provided by views so that it points to this location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution for this is to edit the display footer, set its input format to PHP and print the link yourself like:

```
<?php

  $term_name = 'TERM_NAME'; // set term name depending on how you filter for it
  print l('Read more', 'biblio/term/'. $term_name);

?>
```

if you are using arguments to filter the terms, then you can access the argument(s) like so:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  $arg0 = $view->args[0]; // or whatever index the term name has
?>
```

Otherwise you need to use a custom module and figure out one of the hooks Views implements (e.g. `hook_views_pre_view()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the "Rewrite output of this field" option on the More Link field and use the replacement tokens available to rewrite the url to your desired location. I believe some fields just give a "Show More Link" option. In that case, disable that option. Then add a Link field and use the rewrite tokens to craft the URL you want to send users to.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but I'm looking to change the more link provided for the whole pane -- the one that links to the page view...